# In SQL Server, xml data are saved in a text column, how to query from this column?

Tags: xml, t-sql

In my situation, xml data are saved in a text column, how to query this against this column? For example:

```
create table t1
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    content text
)


insert into t1(content) values ('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <firstName>ooo</firstName>
        <lastName>ppp</lastName>
    </person>
</people>
')
insert into t1(content) values ('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <firstName>mmm</firstName>
        <lastName>nnn</lastName>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstName>aaa</firstName>
        <lastName>bbb</lastName>
    </person>
</people>
')
insert into t1(content) values ('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <firstName>aaa</firstName>
        <lastName>bbb</lastName>
    </person>
</people>
')
```

How to get all rows that have a person, whose first name is ***aaa*** and last name is ***bbb***?

---

Edit:

I changed the insert statement a little, so that you can cast it to **XML** type directly.

Notes:

The content column is of type **text**, since it's an example to represent my actual problem. I'm working on a legacy project.

The second row and third row have a person whose first name is ***aaa*** and last name is ***bbb***, I just need these rows.

Comment: Okay. Do you have control over the database schema? The `text` type is deprecated, and in this column is holding XML data you should absolutely use the `xml` data type (which even allows indexing on XML values if necessary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CAST([content] AS XML) AS xmlcontent 
    FROM 
        t1
) det
WHERE 
xmlcontent.exist('//person[firstName[text()="aaa"] and lastName[text()="bbb"]]') = 1
```

I also added this entry to your set:

```
insert into t1(content) values ('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <firstName>ooo</firstName>
        <lastName>ppp</lastName>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstName>aaa</firstName>
        <lastName>ppp</lastName>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstName>ooo</firstName>
        <lastName>bbb</lastName>
    </person>
</people>
')
```

to show that if there is both a person matching the first name and a different person matching the last name, it does not count it as a match.

Comment: Thank you Locksfree. I just changed my insert statements to let you can cast it directly to xml. You use //firstName[1] to get the firstname, if the person which i need is not the first one in a row, this doesn't work. right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE content.value('(//firstName)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') = 'aaa'
```

Comment: I run the query, but get the following error:
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "content" or the user-defined function or aggregate "content.value", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: It would work if the column was of type xml, rather than text (and the data type as the second argument was change to a varchar type). Is there a reason the column is text?

Comment: @Damien, the use of `text` instead of `xml` or `nvarchar(max)` points to a non-SQL2005-database (either via server or via compatibility level), that's why I asked about the SQL Server version.

Comment: @Lucero - well, the error message is from 2005 or 2008, so it could only be compatibility. (2000 wouldn't want a column with a dot immediately afterwards)

Comment: @Damien, well spotted. Still the use of `text` is deprecated, so that something is strange in that question anyways. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Stealing Dusty's answer, then the following works, *if you eliminate the new lines between the opening quotes and the xml declarations* in your insert statements:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE CONVERT(xml,content).value('(//firstName)[1]', 'varchar(8000)') = 'aaa'
```

Comment: Thank you. But if the person have a firstName aaa is not the first one on a row, then this query won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which uses variables for searching the content, so that you don't have to concatenate the exist query.

```
DECLARE @t1 table (
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    content xml
);
insert into @t1(content) values ('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <firstName>ooo</firstName>
        <lastName>ppp</lastName>
    </person>
</people>');
insert INTO @t1(content) values ('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <firstName>mmm</firstName>
        <lastName>nnn</lastName>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstName>aaa</firstName>
        <lastName>bbb</lastName>
    </person>
</people>');
insert into @t1(content) values ('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <firstName>aaa</firstName>
        <lastName>bbb</lastName>
    </person>
</people>');

DECLARE @firstName nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @lastName nvarchar(50);
SELECT @firstName = 'aaa', @lastName = 'bbb';
SELECT * FROM @t1 t WHERE t.[content].[exist]('//person[firstName=sql:variable("@firstName") and lastName=sql:variable("@lastName")]')=1;
```